# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: failed to allocate memory [Op:AddV2]

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, gpu

Hi I am a beginner in DL and tensorflow,

I created a CNN (you can see the model below)

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=7, activation="relu", input_shape=[512, 640, 3]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.2) #, momentum=0.9, decay=0.1)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I tried building and training it with the cpu and it was completed successfully (but very slowly) so I decided to install tensorflow-gpu.
Installed everything as instructed in https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu).

But now when I am trying to build the model this error comes up:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/thano/Documents/Py_workspace/AI_tensorflow/fire_detection/main.py",
> line 63, in <module>
>     model = create_models.model1()   File "C:\Users\thano\Documents\Py_workspace\AI_tensorflow\fire_detection\create_models.py",
> line 20, in model1
>     model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py",
> line 530, in _method_wrapper
>     result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 217,
> in add
>     output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 977,
> in __call__
>     input_list)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1115,
> in _functional_construction_call
>     inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 848,
> in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call
>     return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)   File
> "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 886,
> in _infer_output_signature
>     self._maybe_build(inputs)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 2659,
> in _maybe_build
>     self.build(input_shapes)  # pylint:disable=not-callable   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py", line 1185, in
> build
>     trainable=True)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 663,
> in add_weight
>     caching_device=caching_device)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py",
> line 818, in _add_variable_with_custom_getter
>     **kwargs_for_getter)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer_utils.py", line
> 129, in make_variable
>     shape=variable_shape if variable_shape else None)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py",
> line 266, in __call__
>     return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py",
> line 227, in _variable_v1_call
>     shape=shape)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py",
> line 205, in <lambda>
>     previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py",
> line 2626, in default_variable_creator
>     shape=shape)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py",
> line 270, in __call__
>     return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)   File
> "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py",
> line 1613, in __init__
>     distribute_strategy=distribute_strategy)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py",
> line 1740, in _init_from_args
>     initial_value = initial_value()   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers\initializers_v2.py",
> line 517, in __call__
>     return self._random_generator.random_uniform(shape, -limit, limit, dtype)   File
> "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers\initializers_v2.py",
> line 973, in random_uniform
>     shape=shape, minval=minval, maxval=maxval, dtype=dtype, seed=self.seed)   File
> "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py",
> line 206, in wrapper
>     return target(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\random_ops.py",
> line 315, in random_uniform
>     result = math_ops.add(result * (maxval - minval), minval, name=name)   File
> "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py",
> line 206, in wrapper
>     return target(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py",
> line 3943, in add
>     return gen_math_ops.add_v2(x, y, name=name)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py",
> line 454, in add_v2
>     _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
> line 6941, in raise_from_not_ok_status
>     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)   File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: failed
> to allocate memory [Op:AddV2]
```

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: What GPU are you using and how much VRAM does it have? Also what is the `batch_size` you are using when training the model?

Comment: Please share your code for training

Answer (score 7):

The error is telling you that it couldn't allocate as much VRAM as you are using. The easiest way to overcome this kind of problem is to reduce to batch-size to a number that fits on your GPU's VRAM.

Answer (score 4):

The error message you received `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: failed to allocate memory [Op:AddV2]` could indicate that your GPU does not have enough memory for the training job you want to run. What GPU are you using and how much vRAM does it have?

When it comes to "Out Of Memory" (OOM) errors when training, the most straightforward thing to do is to **reduce the `batch_size` hyperparameter**.

There's no straightforward way to determine what the largest `batch_size` you can use while training that will fit your GPU's available vRAM other than trial and error. A general rule however, is to use a power of 2 (e.g. `8`, `16`, `32`).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Yes that makes sense based on the error message but the error comes up when creating the model during the first dense layer. It does not reach the training phase so I dont think the problem is in the batch_size. (btw i used sgd optimizer.that's one training instance at a time, right?)
GPU: GTX 1050 , Dedicated video memory=2048MB, Total video memory=10206MB

Comment: @Thanos It'll be easiest for us to help you if you could share your training code. If it's short enough you could edit the original question to include it, or include a link to a GitHub repository with your code.

Comment: 1. Ah right I missed that. 2GBs of video ram isn't a lot but it should be enough for Tensorflow to construct the weights for your first dense layer. Could you try freeing up your video memory by killing some other applications?

2. The optimizer doesn't determine the batch size, that's determined in your call to your training function, which usually is `Model.fit()`, see [documentation and note the `batch_size` argument](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)

Comment: Even if the model is simple the input resolution seems quite high to me for a GTX 1050, have you tried reducing the [512, 640, 3] parameters too?

Comment: @MrK. no I have not tried this.

Comment: Some more observations after messing a little more with tf.
When using the GPU I see (from windows 10 resource monitor) that GPU's memory gets filled up at the moment I am loading the datasets. But only the real GPU memory(1.9GB) and not the VRAM. I tried using tfRecords, keras_image_data_generator and numpy arrays and all of them fill the GPU memory when loading the dataset.
During training though, tfRecords and keras data generators do the work for some simple models. And when I say simple I mean a max 32 neurons at the first dense layer. Anything above that gives OOM errors during trainin

Answer (score 0):

As this implies an out-of-memory scenario, the first thing you should try is to reduce the batch size. This could also happen if you have a very large training dataset size. You can try training the model on a subset of training data and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lot of training samples you might get `ResourceExhaustedError`

`ResourceExhaustedError` from [tensorflow](https://For%20example,%20this%20error%20might%20be%20raised%20if%20a%20per-user%20quota%20is%20exhausted,%20or%20perhaps%20the%20entire%20file%20system%20is%20out%20of%20space.)

> For example, this error might be raised if a per-user quota is
> exhausted, or perhaps the entire file system is out of space.

### How to fix this error:

- Setting smaller `batch_size` when training model using `fit` method:

> `batch_size`: Integer or None. Number of samples per gradient update.

> Which means is higher the batch_size more memory is required while
> training.

- If you are on `Jupyter notebook` try restarting kernel

> Restarting *kernel* will reset your notebook and remove all the memory allocated to variables or methods
> you've defined!

Answer (score 0):

In my case `batch size` was not the issue. The script that I ran previously, the GPU memory was still allocated even after the script ran successfully. I verified this using `nvidia-smi` command, and found out that 14 of 15 GB of vram was occupied. Thus to free the vram you can run the following script and try to run your code again with the same batch size.

```
from numba import cuda
cuda.select_device(0)
cuda.close()
```